# How to delete the last nth characters from the nth line with sed?

Tags: awk, sed

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.4**

I want to delete the last nth characters from the nth line. Here is a simple file and the last 4 characters on each line is the number 4.

```
root@0o0o0o0o0 ~/.ssh # cat remove.txt
00000000004444
55555555555555555555555554444
222222222222222224444
000033334444
111114444
```

To remove the last 4 characters from each line I can execute `sed -i 's/....$//' remove.txt`

```
root@0o0o0o0o0 ~/.ssh # sed -i 's/....$//' remove.txt
root@0o0o0o0o0 ~/.ssh # cat remove.txt
0000000000
5555555555555555555555555
22222222222222222
00003333
11111
```

But what if I wanted to remove the last 4 characters from the 4th line, removing the 3's so the file would look like this:

```
0000000000
5555555555555555555555555
22222222222222222
0000
11111
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/....$//; 4s/....$//' file
```

`4s/....$//` limits search and replace to 4th row.

---

See: `man sed` and `info sed`

Comment: Or `sed -Ei 's/.{4}$//; 4s/.{4}$//' file` if there are a lots of characters to remove. 
Doesn't really make sense here since the command is longer.

Comment: @Freddy Just so I can get a clearer understanding, I want to now remove the last 3 characters from the 30th line. I should have chosen 2 different numbers.

Comment: The first number before `s` is the line number, the number inside `{...}` is the number of characters to replace at the end `$`.

Comment: Note that a line must have enough characters for this to work, otherwise nothing will be removed. If it's not guaranteed, then you can replace each `.` with `.\?` in Cyrus' solution, or each `{4}` with `{0,4}` in Freddy's one.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following in `awk`. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v line="4" -v nofChar="4" '
{
  sub(".{"nofChar"}$","")
}
FNR==line{
  sub(".{"nofChar"}$","")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Detailed explanation:***

```
awk -v line="4" -v nofChar="4" '   ##Starting awk program and setting line variable value, nofChar variable value here.
{
  sub(".{"nofChar"}$","")          ##Substituting last nofChar number of characters at last of the each line here.
}
FNR==line{                         ##Checking if this is same line which OP wants to do 2nd time substitution.
  sub(".{"nofChar"}$","")          ##Substituting last nofChar number of characters at last of the each line here.
}
1                                  ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line.
'  Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case number of characters in all lines are different than specific line then try following. One has to change variable named `nofUsualChar` value.

```
awk -v line="4" -v nofChar="4" -v nofUsualChar="4" '
{
  sub(".{"nofUsualChar"}$","")
}
FNR==line{
  sub(".{"nofChar"}$","")
}
1
'  Input_file
```